# Error when starting python-openstackclient

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, openstack

I installed openstack client via pip:

```
pip3 install python-openstackclient
```

Installation was successful. When I try list servers, it works:

```
$ openstack server list
+--------------------------------------+------------------+--------+--------------------------------+---------------+-----------+
| ID                                   | Name             | Status | Networks                       | Image         | Flavor    |
+--------------------------------------+------------------+--------+--------------------------------+---------------+-----------+
```

When I start just openstack, I recieving error:

```
$ openstack
Exception raised: When using gi.repository you must not import static modules like "gobject". Please change all occurrences of "import gobject" to "from gi.repository import GObject". See: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=709183
```

What causing this problem, how can I resolve it? I red the bugzilla link, but it is from 2014. I am using Kubuntu 18.04 LTS, I install openstack before on my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and I did not have this problem, I just get openstack console so I didn't have to write openstack in front of every command. Can anybody help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem on Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS (Xenial Xerus). 
As current workaround, I suggest to downgrade 'cmd2' package version to 0.6.8 and uninstall 'pyperclip' package at all.  I've tested with openstackclient versions 3.14.0 and 3.14.1, it works. 
The following link could provide you bugfix in future: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python-openstackclient/+bug/1722553.